# HONDA CBR 1000 MODEL 2008

Tags: honda, motorcycle, noise

Please help? My Cbr 1000 is driving me nuts.
At high revs the bike just statters like pa papapa pa pa. Not a backfiring. There is proper spark on all cylinders
Cylinders compresion are fine.  chims was replaced . Petrol pump seviced. Fuel injectors done. Cant get rid of the stuttering

Additional (from comments):
Happening between 5000-8000 RPM.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. What kind of RPMs are we talking about?

Comment: Between 5 and 8000revs

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the air filter and airbox is clear, the ignition timming is correct and there are no vacuum leaks. Then it might be an idea to start testing/replacing things like plugs, leads and coil packs, as these are components that are susceptible to breakdown at high rpm.